# Laravel Missing argument 4 for Dingo\Blueprint\Blueprint::generate()

Tags: laravel, dingo-api

```
 [ErrorException]
```

Missing argument 4 for Dingo\Blueprint\Blueprint::generate(), called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Console/Command/Docs.php
   on line 95 and defined

Exception trace:

```
 () at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/dingo/blueprint/src/Blueprint.php:83
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/dingo/blueprint/src/Blueprint.php:83
 Dingo\Blueprint\Blueprint->generate() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/dingo/api/src/Console/Command/Docs.php:95
 Dingo\Api\Console\Command\Docs->handle() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at     /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:150
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:841
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:189
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:120
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/artisan:36
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved in the master branch of [Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api/tree/master), try pulling this into your development.

IncludePath wasn't included as the 4th parameter in Dingo\Blueprint\Blueprint::generate() function call. Here is the [link](https://github.com/dingo/api/blob/master/src/Console/Command/Docs.php) to the updated file on the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's solution does not work for me. ( with laravel 5.1 )

after replacement of Docs.php, I got errors with Blueprint class.

## So:

In place of Kevin's solution. I found a simple one which works in one second.

:)

modify file:
vendor/dingo/api/src/Console/Command/Docs.php

```
$contents = $this->blueprint->generate($this->getControllers(), $this->argument('name'), $this->argument('version'));
```

with the following code:

```
$contents = $this->blueprint->generate($this->getControllers(), $this->argument('name'), $this->argument('version'),'');
```

by just adding a   `,''`     at the end of the function call, the place of the fourth argument.